# Можно ли как-то обратиться к CSS классу элемента в PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, css, веб-программирование

Необходимо задать условие, если существует эта строка Новинка, то чтобы выполнялись какие-то действия. Можно ли как-то это сделать через PHP, или надо прописывать javascript?

Comment: Какая строка, где, о чём вы вообще? Напишите полноценно и нормально ваш вопрос с примерами кода, который у вас уже есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратиться к css классу через php нет необходимости, поскольку php может дотянуться до любого элемента напрямую. Попробую это продемонстрировать:

Первый вариант

У вас есть переменная со значением в php и выводимый div с классом

```css
.first_class{color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="first_class">some text</div>
```

. Если переменная имеет определенное значение, значит добавляем класс

```
$new_good=true;
?>
```

```css
.first_class{color:green;}
.second_class{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="first_class <?php if($new_good) echo'second_class'?>">some text</div>
```

Если же событие будет происходит на стороне клиента, то это уже другой способ реализации

```js
$('.first_class').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('second_class');
});
```

```css
.first_class{color:green;}
.second_class{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first_class">some text</div>
```